# angular 半角数字検出

Tags: javascript, angularjs

angulerJS  v1.5.8

■疑問点 
入力値のバリデーションの実現方法について

■やりたいこと 
ある文字列の中に半角数字が混在しないようにする 
混在した場合は、エラーメッセージを表示する

■現在のHTML

```
<input required class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" ng-model="name" value="" ng-pattern="???????/" /> 
<div ng-show="myForm.name.$invalid && !myForm.name.$untouched && myForm.name.$error.pattern"> 
<span class="sign" >数字が混在しています</span> 
</div>
```

■現状 
inputタグには、半角数字を除き、どのような文字でも入力可能とします。 
上記ではバリデーションがうまくいっていません。

どのように、半角数字の混在を検出したらよいでしょうか？

Comment: マルチポスト　http://qiita.com/rtp/items/01aa6746c2cdbbb1759a

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/77885

Answer (score 0):

`ng-pattern="???????/"` を `ng-pattern="/^\D+$/"`のように変更すればいいかと思います。
^ : 先頭から
$ : 最後まで
\D: 数字以外の文字
+ : の連続

以下例：

```html
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" >
  <input required class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" ng-model="name" value="" 
  ng-pattern="/^\D+$/" />
  <div ng-show="myForm.name.$invalid && !myForm.name.$untouched && myForm.name.$error.pattern"> 
  <span class="sign" >数字が混在しています</span> 
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```